# Creating a contact form that updates 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql

I am trying to create a form that updates 2 tables in my database. I'm not quite sure how to build this contact form quite yet. So my first short term goal is to simply update my `contact_requests` and `users` tables. I am aiming to do a `one to many` relationship between `users` and `contact_requests`. This allows one `user` to have many `contact_requests`. I am new to rails so I feel like there are gaps in my code and I am making some mistakes as well. Ideally later on, I would like to include a mailer within the form as well but one step at a time.

I currently have a `user` table and a `contact_request` table:

[image]

`user_id` from the `contact_requests` table is a foreign key that references `users.id`

Here is by current schema code:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141127114323) do
  create_table "contact_requests", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "message",    null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "contact_requests", ["user_id"], name: "index_contact_requests_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.string   "first_name",   null: false
    t.string   "last_name",    null: false
    t.string   "email",        null: false
    t.string   "phone_number"
  end
end
```

Here are my models and controllers:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contact_requests
  # validate the presence of the attributes
  validates(:first_name, presence: true)
  validates(:last_name, presence: true)
  validates(:email, presence: true)
end

class ContactRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :message, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
end

class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @contact_request = ContactRequest.new
  end
end
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

form:

```
<%= form_for(:contact, remote: true, class: "contact-input") do |f| %>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.text_field(:user, :first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First name")%>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.text_field(:user, :last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Last name") %>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.email_field(:user, :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email") %>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.telephone_field(:user, :phone_number, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Phone number") %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-input-margin col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_area(:contact_request, :message, class: "form-control contact-margin", rows: "8", placeholder: "Message...") %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit(class: "btn btn-xl") %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening becuase you're specifying `:user` as the first argument in `text_field`:

```
<%= f.text_field(:user, :first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First name")%>
```

You don't need to do this, as `form_for` takes care of this for you. Just this code will do:

```
<%= f.text_field(:first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First name")%>
```

Remove `:user` from all your other fields too.

Comment: Ryan-I think he also needs to put accepts_nested_attributes_for. Also that will mean you will probably want a syntax like  <%= f.text_field("user[first_name]", ... %>

Comment: @JasonFB I would use a fields_for for that, rather than putting the user parameter.